# NGINX serving flask static files

Tags: html, docker, nginx, flask, docker-compose

i was given a task to create 3-Tier architecture that includes :

- NGINX server
- Flask server
- ElasticSearch for DB

**im having problems serving all static files (including index.html) directly from nginx**

**Now i can acsees the Flask server on localhost:5000
but i get 404 on localhost:80**

docker-compose :

```
version: "3.3" 
services: 
    ngnix_my:
        build: ./nginx/.
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links: 
            - app
        depends_on: 
            - app
        networks: 
            - front_net
    app: 
        build: . 
        ports: 
            - "5000:5000" 
        links: 
            - es 
        depends_on: 
            - es 
        networks: 
            - front_net
            - back_net
    es: 
        image: elasticsearch:7.13.1 
        environment: 
            - discovery.type=single-node
        networks: 
            - back_net  
        
networks: 
    front_net:
        driver: bridge
    back_net:
        driver: bridge
```

NGINX Dockerfile :

```
FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./to_serve /
RUN sudo chmod -R 777 /templates/index.html
```

ngnix.conf :

```
events {} # event context needs to be defined to consider config valid

http {
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
  
    location /static {
      root /templates/index.html; 
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://app:5000;
      proxy_redirect     off;

      proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

alright Based on your log and your docker file I think your static files are in
`/to_serve/templates/static` instead of `/templates/index.html` 
so change your nginx config of `/static` location to:

```
location /static {
  root /to_serve/templates/index.html; 
}
```

and test again

Comment: The [root directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) needs to be a directory. In the question and this answer that “directory” doesn’t exist, hence the 404s. I suggest to turn on error logging and read where nginx is looking for files.

Comment: yes,as AD7six said im getting same error with the changed omid suggested

tried to turn on error logs but couldnt understand how..

feeling lost -_-